# Why I can`t select a dynamic string variante inside the Unity UI Input field Inspector?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wanted to give a dynamic string value from an input field to my function. Such simple stuff like an entered name to the function "SetName". Normally I would choose the "on End Edit()" stardard which Unity already provide inside the Inspector for this Input field. The function get called with the dynamic value.
Here is my problem: I have no selection for the dynamic variante, only for the static one (which will not help me here).

[See the detail image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tVoR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You can't pass a dynamic string

That's simply not how those method calls work. You have two options:

1. Pass the *input field* itself and call `.value` on it
2. Pass nothing and have a reference to the input field somewhere else and call `.value` on it.

Do (1) unless you already have a reference to the input field, in which case do (2).